# How to apply DRY to interface implementations involving Form components?

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-xe2, dry

I have an interface `IComm` declaring a routine `SetMonitorLogLevel()`:

```
unit IFaceComm;
interface
type
  TMonitorLogLevel = (mllOnlyImportant, mllAll);

  IComm = Interface(IInterface)
    procedure SetMonitorLogLevel(LogLevel: TMonitorLogLevel);
  end;

end.
```

The interface is implemented by 2 Forms, which are similar to each other, `frmBarComm` and `frmFooComm`, that look like this:

```
TfrmBarComm = class(TForm, IFaceComm.IComm)
  cboDebugLevel: TComboBox;
private
  procedure SetMonitorLogLevel(LogLevel: IFaceComm.TMonitorLogLevel);
end;
```

Note that the 2 Forms have a lot of components in common, such as `cboDebugLevel`, but also can have components the other doesn't.

Both Forms implement `IComm.SetMonitorLogLevel()` in **exactly the same** way:

```
procedure TfrmBarComm.SetMonitorLogLevel(LogLevel: IFaceComm.TMonitorLogLevel);
begin
  case LogLevel of
    IFaceComm.TMonitorLogLevel.mllOnlyImportant:
      Self.cboDebugLevel.ItemIndex := 0;
    IFaceComm.TMonitorLogLevel.mllAll:
      Self.cboDebugLevel.ItemIndex := 1;
  end;
end;
```

How do I avoid violating the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle? I'm faced with this issue quite often, and it's particularly ugly when the copy-pasted routines are much bigger than the simple example I shown above.

Comment: implement the interface in a  class and create your forms inheriting from that class

Comment: @fantaghirocco What happens when you have two such interfaces, A and B.  Then you have Form1 that wants to implement A, Form2 that wants to implement B and Form3 than wants to implement A and B?

Comment: @David Heffernan that's the reason why I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to deal with this is to create another class which implements the interface. It might look like this:

```
type
  TComboBoxCommImplementor = class(TInterfacedObject, IFaceComm.IComm)
  private
    FDebugLevel: TComboBox;
  public
    constructor Create(DebugLevel: TComboBox);
    procedure SetMonitorLogLevel(LogLevel: TMonitorLogLevel);
  end;

constructor TComboBoxCommImplementor.Create(DebugLevel: TComboBox);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FDebugLevel := DebugLevel;
end;

procedure TComboBoxCommImplementor.SetMonitorLogLevel(
  LogLevel: IFaceComm.TMonitorLogLevel);
begin
  case LogLevel of
    IFaceComm.TMonitorLogLevel.mllOnlyImportant:
      FDebugLevel.ItemIndex := 0;
    IFaceComm.TMonitorLogLevel.mllAll:
      FDebugLevel.ItemIndex := 1;
  end;
end;
```

Then in your form implement the interface using delegation:

```
type
  TfrmBarComm = class(TForm, IFaceComm.IComm)
    cboDebugLevel: TComboBox;
  private
    FComm: IFaceComm.IComm;
    property Comm: IFaceComm.IComm read FComm implements IFaceComm.IComm
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TfrmBarComm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FComm := TComboBoxCommImplementor.Create(cboDebugLevel);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer (and thank you kindly for honouring the request in my previous comment)

Answer (score 2):

Create a frame that owns the components which are used on both forms.
The frame implements `IComm`. Both forms using the frame and both forms implement `IComm`. 
The frame is accessible as property that delegates the interface implementation.

It looks like this:

```
type TfrmBarComm = class(TForm)
  FFrameComm: TFrameComm;
public
  property FrameComm: TFrameComm read FFrameComm implements IComm;
end;
```